# Foundation called mkdir(...), it didn't return 0, and errno was set to 2

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm following a tutorial in the book *Creating iOS 5 Apps Develop and Design*. I followed the directions as perfectly as I could but I keep getting this error.

> 2012-10-27 14:40:14.384 Health Beat[10608:1c0f] Foundation called
>   mkdir("/Users/dblock/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/6.0/Applications/5B498D88-3062-4F89-90E2-4B3155C1E325/Library/Documentation/(A
>   Document Being Saved By Health Beat)"), it didn't return 0, and errno
>   was set to 2.

I started this project and then updated to xcode 4.5.1 in the middle of it. I don't know if there is some setting that may make this not work.

[Link to files:](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/81707637/Health%20Beat.zip)

OSX 10.8.2
Xcode 4.5.1 (4G1004)
MBP 15"

Comment: Have you tried resetting your iOS simulator, cleaning the build and trying to build again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you used the constant `NSDocumentationDirectory` instead of the constant `NSDocumentDirectory`.  Probably you typed `NSDoc` and then accepted the autocompletion, and Xcode autocompleted the wrong constant.

To find it, choose Edit > Find > Find in Workspace, or press Command-Shift-F, and search for `NSDocumentationDirectory`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. One little slip up can really throw you off.

Comment: One last question. Is there a reason why when i build and run on iOS 5.1 simulator i get a black screen but when i do it on iOS 6 simulator it runs just fine.

Comment: I'm sure there's a reason but I can't tell you what it is without lots more information.

Comment: You should create a new question.  Describe the problem and post anything that appears in your debug console.

Answer (score 0):

An `errno` value of `2` corresponds to `ENOENT`. Are you sure all the path components before the last exist? `mkdir()` is not recursive.

Comment: Im sorry I'm New at programing objective-c but i did post the code if you don't mind talking a look at it for me that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Either reset your simulator, clean the xcode build and try running it. Or go to 
`/Users/dblock/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications` and remove the folder `5B498D88-3062-4F89-90E2-4B3155C1E325` and run again. That could be the issue here.